# How can I get a parameter request to ignore the case of the user entered text

Tags: java, jsp

In my URL if the user enters in Type I have the following code:

```
String type= (request.getParameter("Type") != null) ? request.getParameter("Type") : request.getParameter("ty");
```

I would like to ignore the case that the user entered. For example a use case can be that the user enters Type, TYPE, TyPe, TYpe, tyPe, or Ty, tY, TY, ty. I want that to just to ignore the case have have it be set with my code. I tried to convert it to lower case but it did not work I get an error. Here is what I tried.

```
String type= (request..toLowerCase().getParameter("Type") != null) ? request.getParameter("Type") : request.getParameter("ty");
```

This did not work.

Comment: For checking `null`, case doesn't matter. What is your actual question ?

Comment: How this should work if user passed two parameters `TypE` and `tyPE`? Or even three parameters? Which one should be used?

Comment: if I pass in any of TypE and tyPE I want it to be recognized as just type and the case to be ignored.

Comment: But what if user passed two parameters? Which one should be used? For example `host/path?TyPE=a&tyPE=b`. What the value should be `a` or `b`?

Comment: as of right now if a user passed in TYPE then String type will be set to null. I want that if the user passed in TYPE as the parameter that String type will be set to the value of that parameter

Comment: I am trying to have a general case to ignore case for any parameter that the user passes for that specific parameter

Comment: For example if url is `host/path?TyPE=a&tyPE=b`. What the result value should be used `a` or `b`?

Comment: my apologies for the confusion. There is only one parameter and that is Type, my goal is to create an error checking algorithm that the user knows that Type is the only parameter. But if they were to by accident type in TyPe then I will still accept that and just treat it as Type. Therefore we will always have host/path?TyPE=a and never a b. We are just working with the parameter and not the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a request to lower-case doesn't make any sense. Converting a string to lower case does.

In any case, I *think* what you're asking is to get a list of parameters, e.g.,

[ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames())

```
Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
```

Then iterate over that list of parameter names, call `toLowerCase()` on them, and make comparisons as your business logic dictates.

You might also use `getParameterMap()` which does what you'd expect.

Comment: I get the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Enumeration<String> to List<String>. Everything else makes sense in your solution. But I am not sure how to fix this error

Comment: @user3767481 My bad; that's the correct signature (obviously).